# Cannot render Object with Thymeleaf: Property or field cannot be found on object of type 'org.parse4j.ParseObject' - maybe not public?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, parse-platform, spring-boot, parse4j

I've been following this guide http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html to learn how to render data models into a Springboot application with Thymeleaf. I have a function that retrieves a list of objects from my Parse-Server and renders them as model attributes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requests", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findRequestsByCurrentUser(Model model) {

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    log.info(String.valueOf(currentUser.getObjectId()));

    findRequestsByCurrentUser(model, currentUser);

    return "requests";
}


private void findRequestsByCurrentUser(Model model, TmtUser currentUser) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> requestsQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstantsUtil.CLASS_REQUEST);
    requestsQuery.whereContains(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_AUTHOR, currentUser.getObjectId());
    try {
        List<ParseObject> requestsArrayList = requestsQuery.find();
        model.addAttribute("requests", requestsArrayList);
        log.info(String.valueOf(requestsArrayList));
        log.info(String.valueOf(requestsArrayList.size()));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is a debug of the model that I send to my view:

[image]

I am able to render the objects because I can include static text instead of its attributes and it will loop 15 times (the number of objects retrieved in the query). But whenever I type `request.requestText` or `request.requestStatus` I get an error:

```
<center>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Requested By</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Reason</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Requested Date</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Status</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="request : ${requests}">
            <div th:switch="${request.requestStatus}">
                <div th:case="Approved">
                    <td th:text="${request.author.objectId" class="initial-name">Employee Initials
                    </td>
                    <td th:text="${request.requestText}">Request Description</td>
                    <td th:text="${request.dateRequested}">Request Date</td>
                    <td th:switch="${request.requestStatus}">
                        <span class="red" th:case="Pending" th:text="Pending">Status</span>
                        <span class="green" th:case="Approved" th:text="Approved">Status</span>
                        <span class="red" th:case="Rejected" th:text="Rejected">Status</span>
                    </td>
                </div>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'requestText' cannot be found on object of type 'org.parse4j.ParseObject' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:207) ~[spring-expression-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:96) ~[spring-expression-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:48) ~[spring-expression-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:358) ~[spring-expression-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88) ~[spring-expression-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120) ~[spring-expression-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267) ~[spring-expression-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.3.M1.jar:3.0.3.M1]
    ... 116 common frames omitted
```

Why are the ParseObject attributes not accessible to Thymeleaf?

When I print `${request}` on its own I get: `org.parse4j.ParseObject@5975192b`, for example. I can also retrieve `${request.objectId}`. What is the syntax for retrieving the attributes? `${request.data.requestText}` does not seem to work either...

Comment: I think it's because Thymeleaf expects an accessor method for ``${request.requestText}`` in the form of ``.getRequestText()`` returning the String ``requestText``. Since ParseObject on its own does not have these methods I'll have to create the data model locally and then pass that on as a model attribute for Thymeleaf to render... So instead of passing a ParseObject I'll pass a custom one that extends ParseObject matching my data model. I'll try that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works when access your model attributes using a Hashmap, bypassing the need to create a custom ParseObject:

```
<td th:text="${request.get('requestText')}">Request Description</td>
```